# Showing wrong forecast

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm doing a weather web app using JS and an API. Everything is working fine except when it comes to the current forecast, it should be cloudy and show a cloud image but instead of that it shows a sun image. I'm storing the weather ID in a variable **(weather)** and the weather name in other **(weatherN)** so I can display them at the same time:

(There is a lot of else ifs, the only important ones are the last two)

(The photo names are in spanish I leave the translation of the important ones: (sol --> sun) (nube --> cloud))

```
<script class="scr">
            fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Denia&appid=ece23eaa3a8d940b327a0cdc41c1e344&units=metric')
            .then(res=> res.json())
            
            .then(data=> {

                console.log(data);
            
                let temp = `
                    <p>
                    ${data.main.temp} ºC                   
                    </p>
                `;
                document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
                

                let weatherN = `
                    ${data.weather[0].main}
                `;

                let weather = `
                    ${data.weather[0].id}
                `;
                
                parseInt(weather)
                if (weather >= 200 && stat <=232) {
                    ima = `
                        <img src="Rayo.png" height="200px" width="100%" alt="foto">
                    `;
                    document.getElementById('ima').innerHTML = ima;
                    document.getElementById('stat').innerHTML = weatherN;
                }

                else if (weather >= 300 && stat <=321) {
                    ima = `
                        <img src="Lluvia.png" height="200px" width="100%" alt="foto">
                    `;
                    document.getElementById('ima').innerHTML = ima;
                    document.getElementById('stat').innerHTML = weatherN;
                }

                else if (weather >= 500 && stat <=531) {
                    ima = `
                        <img src="Lluvia.png" height="200px" width="100%" alt="foto">
                    `;
                    document.getElementById('ima').innerHTML = ima;
                    document.getElementById('stat').innerHTML = weatherN;
                }

                else if (weather >= 600 && stat <=622) {
                    ima = `
                        <img src="nieve.png" height="200px" width="100%" alt="foto">
                    `;
                    document.getElementById('ima').innerHTML = ima;
                    document.getElementById('stat').innerHTML = weatherN;
                }

                else if (weather >= 700 && stat <=781) {
                    ima = `
                        <img src="fog.png" height="200px" width="100%" alt="foto">
                    `;
                    document.getElementById('ima').innerHTML = ima;
                    document.getElementById('stat').innerHTML = weatherN;
                }

                else if (weather >= 800) {
                    ima = `
                        <img src="sol.png" height="200px" width="100%" alt="foto">
                    `;
                    document.getElementById('ima').innerHTML = ima;
                    document.getElementById('stat').innerHTML = weatherN;
                }

                else if (weather >= 801 && stat <= 804) {
                    ima = `
                        <img src="nube.png" height="200px" width="100%" alt="foto">
                    `;
                    document.getElementById('ima').innerHTML = ima;
                    document.getElementById('stat').innerHTML = weatherN;
                }
```

And here I leave the divs:

```
<div id="main" class="main">
    
    <div id="ima"></div>

    <div id="stat" class="stat"></div>

    <div id="data" class="scr"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Weather currently is 804

Comment: What is the value of `stat`? I do not see a place where something is assigned to this variable.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky i'm freaking dumb and blind, I forgot to substitute stat for weather. Thanks man <3

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky you can answer with that comment and i'll mark it as the correct one thenks again

Comment: One other issue: you will never hit the last `else-if`, since if `weather >= 801`, you will already have hit the case `weather >= 800`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yeah I noticed that. I've changed it to `weather == 800`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comment above, you didn't set the value of `stat`.

Also you should try to use `let weather = data.weather[0].id` instead of

```
let weather = `
    ${data.weather[0].id}
`;
```

The first one (just `data.weather[0].id`) returns an integer, due to the JSON response contains integer (`"id": 804,`).

If you use `parseInt`, you should assign the result of this function to your variable, for ex., `weather = parseInt(weather)`. Otherwise, the variable remains unchanged.